# Amazon SP-API - submit listings item patch request (C# code)

Tags: request, patch

I am using C# code to make API call to Amazon SP-API. I have read though these documents:

https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api-blog/docs/automate-your-sp-api-calls-using-the-c-sdk

https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/listings-items-api-v2021-08-01-use-case-guide#step-1-submit-listings-item-patch-request

I have successfully submitted listings GET request, but not sure how to submit PATCH request. I am trying to change the price of an item. Below is my code. The "body" parameter is where I got stuck. I am not sure If I do it right. Please advise.

```
public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        LWAAuthorizationCredentials lwaAuthorizationCredentials = new LWAAuthorizationCredentials
        {
            ClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            RefreshToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            Endpoint = new Uri("https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token")
        };

        ListingsApi listingsApi = new ListingsApi.Builder()
            .SetLWAAuthorizationCredentials(lwaAuthorizationCredentials)
            .Build();

        string sellerId = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
        List<string> marketplaceIds = new List<string>();
        marketplaceIds.Add("ATVPDKIKX0DER");
        string sku = "XXX-YYY-ZZZ";
        
//*** This is the part where I got error
//*** I am not sure if I am doing correctly
ListingsItemPatchRequest body = new ListingsItemPatchRequest();
        body =  {
            "productType":"CELLULAR_PHONE",
              "patches":[

                {
                "op":"replace",
                  "path":"/attributes/purchasable_offer",
                  "value":[
                    {
                    "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER",
                      "currency": "USD",
                      "our_price": [
                        {
                        "schedule": [
                                              {
                            "value_with_tax": 15.00
                                              }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }

              ]
            }

        ListingsItemSubmissionResponse result = listingsApi.PatchListingsItem(sellerId, sku,  marketplaceIds, body);
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToJson());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (LWAException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LWA Exception when calling SellersApi#getMarketplaceParticipations");
        Console.WriteLine(e.getErrorCode());
        Console.WriteLine(e.getErrorMessage());
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    catch (ApiException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception when calling SellersApi#getMarketplaceParticipations");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```